# Visual Studio 2022 Pro is giving the error "The connection properties object must be of type SqlConnectionProperties or OleDBSqlConnectionPropertiies"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, sqlconnection

I am trying to add a database connection to MS SQL Server in Visual Studio 2022 and this is the error I am getting on the "Choose Data Source" screen.

> The connection properties object must be of type SqlConnectionProperties or OleDBSqlConnectionPropertiies

I have already tried uninstalling VS 2022 Pro and reinstalling after .net framework. However, that didn't help and I am getting the same error.

Kindly help me resolving this without reinstalling OS (Windows 11) because I have lot of things set up.